# reshape2 and wide (imputed) time variables

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I know `reshape` from base R can convert to a long format where the time is imputed from the stub variable names `A` and `B`, for example:

```
wide = data.frame(A.2010 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                  A.2011 = c('f', 'g', 'd'),
                  B.2010 = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                  B.2011 = c('G', 'G', 'H'),
                  z = runif(3),
                  x = runif(3))

wide
#  A.2010 A.2011 B.2010 B.2011         z          x
#1      a      f      A      G 0.3626823 0.67212468
#2      b      g      B      G 0.3726911 0.09663248
#3      c      d      C      H 0.9807237 0.31259394
```

Becomes:

```
reshape(wide, direction = 'long', sep = '.',
        varying = c('A.2010', 'A.2011', 'B.2010', 'B.2011'))
#               z          x time A B id
#1.2010 0.3626823 0.67212468 2010 a A  1
#2.2010 0.3726911 0.09663248 2010 b B  2
#3.2010 0.9807237 0.31259394 2010 c C  3
#1.2011 0.3626823 0.67212468 2011 f G  1
#2.2011 0.3726911 0.09663248 2011 g G  2
#3.2011 0.9807237 0.31259394 2011 d H  3
```

Can I accomplish the same with `reshape2::melt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `reshape` in base r is the best tool to do this, since there is no similar functionality in the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package. You can however, achieve something similar with the `patterns` function in `melt.data.table`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

wide = data.table(wide)

long = melt(wide, id.vars = c("z", "x"), measure = patterns("^A", "^B"),
            value.name = c("A", "B"), variable.name = "time")

> long
           z         x time A B
1: 0.3421681 0.8432707    1 a A
2: 0.1243282 0.5096108    1 b B
3: 0.3650165 0.1441660    1 c C
4: 0.3421681 0.8432707    2 f G
5: 0.1243282 0.5096108    2 g G
6: 0.3650165 0.1441660    2 d H
```

Notice that `melt` recognizes the varying "time", and groups them correctly, but does not use 2010 and 2011 as desired. A workaround is to recode the levels manually, which should be trivial.

```
levels(long$time) = c("2010", "2011")

> long
           z         x time A B
1: 0.3421681 0.8432707 2010 a A
2: 0.1243282 0.5096108 2010 b B
3: 0.3650165 0.1441660 2010 c C
4: 0.3421681 0.8432707 2011 f G
5: 0.1243282 0.5096108 2011 g G
6: 0.3650165 0.1441660 2011 d H
```

I hope this helps!